# ASP.Net UpdateProgress won't go away when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mobile, updateprogress

In my Master Page, I am adding either the jQuery or jQuery Mobile script file, depending on if the user is browsing from a mobile device. I have discovered that jQuery Mobile does not play well with the ASP.Net AJAX UpdateProgress control.

On some of my pages where I am using an UpdatePanel, the UpdateProgress control will not go away after partial-page postbacks in the UpdatePanel. However, if I just use the normal jQuery script, it works fine.

I would just use the regular jQuery script file, but many of the jQuery plugins I have implemented do not work on mobile devices. For example, I am using an input mask plugin for some textboxes, and it will not let me type in them when mobile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the updateprogress control not go away, means that you have javascript error. Look this errors to find the problem.

Comment: Wow, now that you mention it, I am getting a '$ is not defined' error. Does jQuery Mobile load later in the page life cycle than regular jQuery? It seems like jQuery Mobile is not fully loaded when my script runs. Here is my script: Sys.Application.add_load(function () {

    $('.maskDate').mask("99/99/9999");
    $('.maskPhone').mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $('.maskSSN').mask("999-99-9999");
    $('.maskUtAcctNum').mask("9999-99999-9999-999");

});

Comment: The Sys.App... is a part of the ScriptManager, maybe you do not have load the scriptmanager ? Anyway, its up to you to find what you do not load correctly.